# Using Ruby and Sinatra, how can I upload a csv file and insert each row into a postgres database?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, csv, sinatra

I am using Sequel, Sinatra, Postgres and ruby. I have a form to upload a csv file which works fine, the problem is then parsing and inserting the fields from the csv file into a postgres database. The structure of the csv file is as follows:

```
first,last,designation,email,phone,company,remarks,owner,date
John,McAndrew,CEO,debra.wagman@callcreditgroup.com,44 113 388 4300,Callcredit Information Group,none,tim@xxxx.jp,now()
```

The postgres database has the same fields.

I want to keep the headers and then loop through the records (there may be 100s) and insert into the database. I am experimenting with just one field first then all of the fields need to be inserted. The ruby code I have so far is:

```
 require 'csv'
    post '/upload' do
      file_data = params[:myfile][:tempfile].read
      #file_data = params[:file].read
      csv_rows  = CSV.parse(file_data, headers: true)
      owner = 'tim@xxxx.jp'
      csv_rows.map do |row| 
       {firstname => row[:first]}
          DB[:prospects].insert( :first =>  firstname, :owner => owner )
      end
     end
```

This does not work and I get this: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "firstname" does not exist.

Then I tried:

```
 require 'csv'
    post '/upload' do
      file_data = params[:myfile][:tempfile].read
      #file_data = params[:file].read
      csv_rows  = CSV.parse(file_data, headers: true)
      owner = 'tim@xxxx.jp'
      csv_rows.each do |row| 

       DB[:prospects].insert( :first =>  row[:first], :owner => owner )

          end
      end
```

which does not return an error but it only inserts the variable owner, it completely ignores row[:first] or cannot find it.

What is the correct approach guys? Thanks!

This works (with help from SoulRebel):

```
post '/upload' do
  file_data = params[:myfile][:tempfile].read
  #file_data = params[:file].read
  csv_rows  = CSV.parse(file_data, headers: true)
  owner = 'tim@platformone.jp'
  csv_rows.each do |row| 

   DB[:prospects].insert( :first =>  row[:first], :owner => owner )

      end
end
```

and this works too, figured out by me, after trial and error:

```
post '/uploading' do
  file_data = params[:myfile][:tempfile].read
  csv_rows  = CSV.parse(file_data, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol)
  owner = 'tim@xxxx.jp'
  remarks = 'none yet'
  csv_rows.each do |row| 
      DB[:prospects].insert( :first =>  row[:first], :last => row[:last], :designation => row[:designation], :email => row[:email], :phone => row[:phone], :company => row[:company], :industry => row[:industry], :city => row[:city], :country => row[:country], :status => row[:status],  :remarks => remarks, :owner => owner )
    end
  return "File successfully uploaded"
end
```

Note the addition of "header_converters: :symbol"

As always, thanks to the SO community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CSV.foreach($csv_fname, :headers => true) do |csv_obj|
    puts csv_obj['first'] #just to verify that parsing is working well
    DB[:prospects].insert( :first =>  cvs_obj['first'], :owner => csv_obj['owner'] )

end
```

Comment: Looks cool, thanks. I will try it out and then give you feedback with a nice green tick, if it works. I am grateful for your help and advice.

Comment: thanks with a bit of tinkering, works fine. I have amended the code above to reflect your suggestion and present the correctly working snippet. Also, worth noting, is that the inclusion of header_converters: :symbol solves all problems.